# how to debug when xinetd says : got signal 17 (child exited)

Tags: ssh, vsftpd, xinetd

I am trying to start services vsftpd and sshd using xinetd. my config files are as follows.

1. /etc/xinetd.conf

   ```
   defaults
   {
   instances               = 60
   log_type                = FILE /var/log/xinetdlog
   log_on_success          = HOST PID
   log_on_failure          = HOST
   cps                     = 25 30
   only_from       = localhost
   }
   includedir /etc/xinetd.d
   ```
2. /etc/xinetd.d/ftp

   ```
   service ftp
   {
   disable = no
   server = /usr/sbin/vsftpd
   server_args = -l
   user = root
   socket_type = stream
   protocol = tcp
   wait = no
   instances = 4
   flags = REUSE
   nice = 10
   log_on_success      += DURATION HOST USERID
   only_from = 127.0.0.1 10.0.0.0/24
   }
   ```
3. /etc/xinetd.d/ssh

   ```
   service ssh
   {
   disable = no
   log_on_failure += USERID
   server = /usr/sbin/sshd
   user = root
   socket_type = stream
   protocol = tcp
   wait = no
   instances = 20
   flags = REUSE
   only_from = 127.0.0.1 10.0.0.0/24
   }
   ```

Even though i've included only_from attribute, vsftp server as well as ssh server are refusing connection from localhost. while vsftp and ssh servers are working fine individually when i check with "service vsftpd start" and "service ssh start". when i did debug using "xinetd -d" throug terminal i got the output as

```
13/10/20@00:06:08: DEBUG: 3592 {cnf_start_services} Started service: ftp
13/10/20@00:06:08: DEBUG: 3592 {cnf_start_services} Started service: ssh
13/10/20@00:06:08: DEBUG: 3592 {cnf_start_services} mask_max = 8, services_started = 2
13/10/20@00:06:08: NOTICE: 3592 {main} xinetd Version 2.3.14 started with libwrap loadavg options compiled in.
13/10/20@00:06:08: NOTICE: 3592 {main} Started working: 2 available services
13/10/20@00:06:08: DEBUG: 3592 {main_loop} active_services = 2
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {main_loop} select returned 1
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {server_start} Starting service ftp
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {main_loop} active_services = 2
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3607 {exec_server} duping 9
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {main_loop} active_services = 2
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {main_loop} select returned 1
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {check_pipe} Got signal 17 (Child exited)
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {child_exit} waitpid returned = 3607
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {server_end} ftp server 3607 exited
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {svc_postmortem} Checking log size of ftp service
13/10/20@00:06:16: INFO: 3592 {conn_free} freeing connection
13/10/20@00:06:16: DEBUG: 3592 {child_exit} waitpid returned = -1
```

both services are getting started but neither of them is working.

after banging for 3-4 hours i still don't have any clue about this error. Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: I have suggested that this question belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes! i posted the same question few minutes back on stackoverflow. but i was suggested to post on this site. superuser.com thanks!

Comment: This definitely belongs to either SuperUser or ServerFault. Anyway, does **vsftpd** log anything?

Comment: where can i find the vsftpd log if it is run by xinetd. when i checked /var/log/vsftpd.log it had only logs when it had run by vsftpd daemon and not by xinetd daemon.

Answer (score 0):

The [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page says:

> ```
> Signal     Value     Action   Comment
> ---------------------------------------------------------
> SIGCHLD   20,17,18    Ign     Child stopped or terminated
> ```

This means that whenever a child process stops i.e. **vsftpd** or **sshd**, the parent - **xinetd** - receives signal 17 (which would be ignored by default, but in your case it's not).

You also need to start **sshd** with `-i`:

> **-i**
>
> Specifies that sshd is being run from inetd(8).  sshd is normally not run
>   from inetd because it needs to generate the server key before it can respond
>   to the client, and this may take tens of seconds.  Clients would have to wait
>   too long if the key was regenerated every time.  However, with small key
>   sizes (e.g. 512) using sshd from inetd may be feasible.

I don't know what **vsftpd** version you're using, but **vsftpd-2.2.2-6.el6_0.1** works fine if I set `listen=NO` in **/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf** and run it without any arguments.

Comment: I have added sshd arguments as `server_args = -i` to /etc/xinetd.d/ssh file. but still, it is not working.

Comment: @FaizanShaik, it works fine for me with **xinetd-2.3.14-39.el6_4.i686** and **openssh-server-5.3p1-84.1.el6.i686**.